# Convex hull on the mask outputted by BackgroundSubtractorMOG

Tags: opencv, convex-hull, background-subtraction

I am using the `BackgroundsubtractorMOG()` to basically extract a mask to separate out the foreground. I am then using `convexHull()` on the mask to locate the position of a moving object.

But i am getting the following error:

```
openCV Error: Assertion failed (nelems >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)) in convexHull, file /home/ameya/OpenCV2.4.2/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 1947
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/ameya/OpenCV2.4.2/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:1947: error: (-215) nelems >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function convexHull
```

I have checked the no. of elements as well as type-casted the mask matrix. But the error still persists.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem before. I am using OpenCV 2.4.2

Comment: this is either the wrong number of elements passed to the function or the wrong type (not 32F float or 32S signed int) as the error showcases it

Answer (score 2):

Use this format, it will help (notice typecasting to `Mat`):

```
convexhull(Mat(inputarray),hull,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

are you calling convexhull on your mask image there ?

it's supposed to work with point2d(or index) vectors, eg. from findContours()

Comment: I am working with Point2f vector of points. I am providing the convexHull() function with the indices of white pixels in the mask.

Comment: oh, sorry then, -- that would have been a too easy case ;)